# Programy chatbot executes Django command

Tags: django, chatbot

I am studying the way to integrate [programy](https://github.com/keiffster/program-y) to my Django application. First thing I would like to see is `chatbot` be able to execute Django-command. For example

> I: How many orders are created today?
>   bot: They are {{ Order.objects.filter(...).count() }} orders

When I look at the document. It mentions only AIML, but does not mention anything about execute further command.

**Possible workaround:**
It seems to be impossible since `<set>, <get>` tags are static and `programy` has to compile and loaded into the memory before bot start conversation.

**Drawback:**
Doing the pre-queries and set the variable. Bot will present the outdated value.

**Question:**
How do I let bot execute Django by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documenation for Program-Y it does have support for an [External REST Service](https://github.com/keiffster/program-y/wiki/External-Rest).

If you had a Django application which presented a [REST API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example) then Program-Y should hook straight into it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very good idea to do separation of concern at REST API hook layer!